# Using MethodInfo.GetCurrentMethod() in anonymous methods

Tags: c#, .net, reflection, anonymous-methods

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Action a = () => Console.WriteLine(MethodInfo.GetCurrentMethod().Name);
    a();
}
```

This code will return an obscure string like so: `<Main>b__0`.

Is there a way of ignoring the anonymous methods and get a more readable method name?

Comment: And what name do you expect for an _anonymous_ method??

Comment: I hold no grudge for MS anon. method name generator. I just wondered if there's a way of digging in the stack trace for the nearest non-anonymous method? Is there a way of knowing that a MethodInfo instance is anonymous?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could capture it outside:

```
var name = MethodInfo.GetCurrentMethod().Name + ":subname";
Action a = () => Console.WriteLine(name);
```

Other than that; no.

Comment: Yes. I think captured variables is the best and most simple solution.

Answer (score 6):

No, there isn't. That's why it is an anonymous method. The name is automatically generated by the compiler and guaranteed to be unique. If you want to get the calling method name you could pass it as argument:

```
public static void Main()
{
    Action<string> a = name => Console.WriteLine(name);
    a(MethodInfo.GetCurrentMethod().Name);
}
```

or if you really want a meaningful name you will need to provide it:

```
public static void Main()
{
    Action a = MeaningfullyNamedMethod;
    a();
}

static void MeaningfullyNamedMethod()
{
    Console.WriteLine(MethodInfo.GetCurrentMethod().Name);
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, I can't pass parameters because it's a 3rd party API, and I don't want to wrap it just for that. Is there a way of digging in the stack trace? Is there a way of knowing that a `MethodInfo` instance is anonymous?

Comment: @HuBeZa, you could test whether the MethodInfo is decorated with the `[CompilerGenerated]` attribute. This is a required condition and a good candudate for being an anonymous method but obviously not sufficient condition: `var isCompilerGenerated = MethodInfo.GetCurrentMethod().IsDefined(typeof(CompilerGeneratedAttribute), true);`

Answer (score 3):

If you are looking for getting the name of the function in which the anonymous method resides in you could travel the stack and get the name of the calling method. Do note though, that this would only work as long as your desired method name is one step up in the hierarchy. 
Maybe there's a way of travelling up until you reach a non-anonymous method.

For more information see:
http://www.csharp-examples.net/reflection-calling-method-name/