# Get Action from Task in C#

Tags: c#, .net, task-parallel-library, task

Having instantiated one or more `Task` objects in C#, like this for example:

```
var tasks = new List<Task>
{
    Task.Factory.StartNew(MyWorker.DoWork),
    Task.Factory.StartNew(AnotherWorker.DoOtherWork)
};
```

Is there a way to get the `Action` method from the task object? In other words, can I return the `Action` of `MyWorker.DoWork` from its task?

I'm trying to be able to log the status of each task, like this:

```
Task.WaitAll(tasks.ToArray(), new TimeSpan(0, 0, 1));

var msg = tasks.Aggregate(string.Empty,
    (current, task) =>
        current + $"{task.Action}: {task.Status}{Environment.NewLine}");
```

The string value of `msg` would be:

```
MyWorker.DoWork RanToCompletion
AnotherWorker.DoOtherWork Running
```

(The `{task.Action}` portion of my sample doesn't exist and wouldn't compile, of course)

Comment: What should it print if you do this: `Task.Factory.StartNew(() => {})` ?

Comment: Also - see this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/12098662/563532 - You might have to modify it a bit to include the declaring class (MyWorker / AnotherWork) etc. Do be aware, though, of situations where methods do not necessarily have human-friendly names as per my above comment

Comment: Create a wrapper service that you use to create tasks. Inside that, create a task and along with it store the Action to reference later on. Essentially using the adaptor pattern.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Getting the method name of a task](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12085347/getting-the-method-name-of-a-task)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The delegate is stored in the `m_action` data member on the `Task` class. You can see that in the [reference source](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/threading/Tasks/Task.cs,158).

However, that data member is `internal` and there's no public way to get to it. You can however use reflection to pick into the insides of a task and look at the contents of `m_action`.

For example this:

```
var fooTask = new Task(Foo);
var fieldInfo = typeof(Task).GetField("m_action", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance);
var value = fieldInfo.GetValue(fooTask);
Console.WriteLine(((Action)value).Method);
```

Outputs (in my specific example):

```
Void Foo()
```

A better design option would be to just start all your tasks from a single place in your code that registers all the information you would need outside of the `Task` itself and use that to log the status.

Comment: Thank you. Because `m_action` is set to null when the `Task` completes, and I call `Task.WaitAll` before interrogating the tasks, I followed your suggestion to change the design. Very informative answer in both the technical aspect and the design suggestion.