# C# caching with delegates

Tags: c#, caching, delegates

I'm working on a simple cache class for my application.

```
using System;
namespace Program {
  public class Cache {
    public delegate int CacheMethodInt();
    public static int Get(CacheMethodInt method) {
      //todo: generate cachekey here
      return method.Invoke();
    }
  }

  public class Calculator {
    public int Add(int x, int y) {
      return x + y;
    }
  }

  class Program {
    static void Main(string[] args) {
      Calculator c = new Calculator();
      Console.WriteLine(Cache.Get(() => c.Add(1, 2)));
    }
  }
}
```

In `Cache:Get` I need to check whether the return value is already cached and if so return it without invoking the method. The problem is that I can't figure out how to generate a good cachekey. In this case I would like something like this:

```
Calculator:Add:1(int):2(int)
```

Is it possible to get this info in `Cache:Get`? I'm using .NET 2.0.

Comment: It doesn't make sense to cache data that is this cheap to re-calculate.  Use the [homework] tag for homework questions.

Answer (score 1):

It's possible using reflection.

As alternative, on a project I used Postsharp for the same purposes. As benefit more generic and common approach

And do not forget about cache invalidation or expiration.

Related question shows how to get MethodInfo and method name:

[Using MethodInfo.GetCurrentMethod() in anonymous methods](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4704910/using-methodinfo-getcurrentmethod-in-anonymous-methods)

When you have MethodInfo than you can get all you need